# interfaces in java - MyClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method eq(Object) in MyClass error

Tags: interface, overriding

I know there is a Comparable interface, trying to figure out how to write my own.

### Here's the interface

```
public interface MyComparable {
    public boolean lt(Object other);
}
```

### and a class that implements it and packages an int (yes, I know there is an Integer class)

```
public  class  MyInteger implements MyComparable {
    private int value;

    public MyInteger(int v)
    {   value = v;  }

    public void set(int v)
    {   value = v;  }

    public int get()
    {   return value;   }

    public boolean lt(MyInteger other)
    {   return get() < other.get(); } 
}
```

I get " MyInteger is not abstract and does not override abstract method eq(Object) in MyInteger error". MyComparable doesn't declare an eq method. So it's comping from the superclass but I don't understand.